# Bounding the finite sum of $\frac {\log n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I'm completely lost in my class on Additive Number Theory.

I've been trying to show that there exists a constant B such that

$$\sum_{n \le x}\frac{\log n}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\log ^2x + B + O\left(\frac{\log  x}{x}\right)
$$

I've honestly been working on it all night and can't come up with a good way to approach the problem!! Help!!!

The foreign O notation is really messing with me.

Comment: You really need to get comfortable with the $O$ notation if you're going to do number theory.

Comment: Big hint: You shouldn't need much more than the Euler-Maclaurin formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula (along with knowing how to compute $\int\frac{1}{x}\log x\, dx$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abel's partial summation technique:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} a(n) f(n) & = \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n) (A(n)- A(n-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n) f(n) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n-1) f(n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n)f(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} A(n) f(n+1)\\
& = A(N)f(N) - A(0) f(1) - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))
\end{align*}
(The above is nothing but the discrete version of integration by parts).

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a(n) f(n) = \int_{1^-}^{N^+} f(t) d(A(t)) =  f(t) A(t) \rvert_{1^-}^{N^+} - \int_{1^-}^{N^+} A(t) f'(t) dt$$ (The second integral can be interpreted as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.)

Consider the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq N} \frac{\log(n)}n$. Choose $a(n) = 1$ and $f(n) = \frac{\log(n)}n$ and you will get what you want.

Comment: Hey Marvis, thanks for the response! Ya I missed the class earlier this week on partial summation - looks like I should go review! But thanks again, appreciated!!